# How to specialize a given template for a template

Tags: c++

Is it possible to specialize this template for any basic_string's?

```
template<class T> struct X {};
```

Since basic_string is a template itself, I know this would be a solution:

```
template <template <class, class, class> class T> struct X {}; template <> struct X<basic_string> {};
```

However, I would like to know if the language allows to preserve the first template definition, by specializing it somehow for basic_string's only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
#include <string>

template <typename> struct X;

template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename TAlloc>
struct X<std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits, TAlloc>>
{
    // ...
};
```

Your primary template takes one **type** parameter, so every specialization must supply one type parameter for `X`, one way or another.